# How to send a message back to UIScrollView from a NavigationController stack?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview

My view controllers are structured like this:

```
> UIWindow 
> - RootViewController with UIScrollView (2 pages, pagingEnabled)
> -- UINavigationController (in the first page of the scrolling view)
> --- HomePageViewController (plus other ViewControllers pushed on the stack)  
> -- MinutiaViewController (second page)
```

UIScrollView holds the UInavigationController as a subview 
`[scrollView addSubview:navController.view];`

In my scenario I want to:

> - disable UIScrollView scrolling (scrollEnable=NO) once a new view is pushed onto the UINavigationViewController
> - enable UIScrollView again (scrollEnable=YES) once the new view is popped and the UINavigationController shows its root again
>     (HomePageViewController)

I figured out how to disable the scrollView scrolling when pushing a new view.

**But cannot figure out how to enable the scrollView scrolling when the new view pops off the stack.**

So far I tried

> 1 triggering viewWillAppear; viewWillDisappear; manually and sending a
>   message to UIScrollView from HomePageViewController's viewWillAppear
>   e.g.

```
    [self.navigationController.parentViewController performSelector:@selector(enableScrollAgain)];
```

> 2 designated the RootViewController as a UINavigationController delegate to handle its
>   events

None seems to work so far. All advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Notifications ? You could add the RootView to observe a notification form  the navigation controller, when you get that notification you can disable scrolling. Look into NotificationCenter.

Hope this helps